The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first - MAUI
When assigning to Content for a second time in a MAUI app page, I get the following error:
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
Showing my code first, then the solution I found.
activityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator { Color = Colors.White };
activityIndicatorStackLayout = new VerticalStackLayout
{
    HeightRequest = 60D,
    WidthRequest = 60D,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    Children = { activityIndicator }
};

Content = activityIndicatorStackLayout;

....
....
....
....

Content = new VerticalStackLayout 
{
    Spacing = 25D,
    Children =
    {
        upperStackLayout,
        activityIndicator
    }
};


Posting here the solution I found.

I can't reproduce your problem. I copied your code and assign the content first time in the constructor , second time in the OnAppearing method. It worked well on all the platforms. I used .net 8.0.

The parent of activityIndicator is activityIndicatorStackLayout.
One solution is to use activityIndicator everywhere, instead of activityIndicatorStackLayout.
The solution I chose was to replace activityIndicator with activityIndicatorStackLayout in the second Content assignment:
Content = new VerticalStackLayout 
{
    Spacing = 25D,
    Children =
    {
        upperStackLayout,
        activityIndicatorStackLayout
    }
};


Seems like it might be a Maui bug - worked in Xamarin.
